# Is the skew normal distribution a member of the exponential family

Tags: normal-distribution, exponential-family, skew-normal-distribution

I'm trying to proof that the skew normal distribution ist part of the exponential family, but I cannot find a solution. So is it a member of the exponential family or are my assumptions misleading?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution

Comment: Are you including location and scale parameters or not?

Comment: See http://paduaresearch.cab.unipd.it/7321/1/WP_2002_13.pdf    Very short: The skew-normal family as defined by Azzalini is not itself an exponential family, but it generates an exponential family (via exponential tilting) which can be identified by a certain extended skew-normal family.